# Understanding inner generic classes

Tags: java, generics

I wrote the following code:

```
public class Test<T> {

    public void method(){
        B b = new B();
    }

    public class B{ }
}

//Some method in some class contains the following lines    
Test<Integer> t = null;
Test.B b = t.new B(); //warning Test.B is a raw type
```

Why did I get this warning? The declation of the inner type `B` doesn't contain type parameter, therefore it's not a generic type. Moreover, [the specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.2) gives us the following:

> A class is generic if it declares one or more type variables

The class `B` doesn't declare the type variables. So why is it a generic type?

Comment: This line `Test.B b = t.new B();` compiles? Could someone with more Java knowledge explain what `t.new` means? This looks like a syntax error to my eyes.

Comment: @thatidiotguy That's a classical qualified class-instance cration expr. [Look](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9)

Comment: @ScottHunter `Object`. `B` does not inherit from any class, so it inherits from `Object` implicitly.

Comment: Yes, that's the standard syntax for instantiating an instance of an inner class. A `B` in this case cannot exist without a corresponding instance of `A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the specification of generic classes does not clearly cover your scenario. But the specification of [raw types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8) does:

> More precisely, a raw type is defined to be one of:
>
> - The reference type that is formed by taking the name of a generic type declaration without an accompanying type argument list.
> - An array type whose element type is a raw type.
> - **A non-`static` member type of a raw type R that is not inherited from a superclass or superinterface of R.**

Comment: BTW, there's a note below the quote you provided: __The type of the member(s) of Inner depends on the type parameter of Outer. If Outer is raw, Inner must be treated as raw as well, as there is no valid binding for T.__ He didn't say it explicitly, that `Test<Integer>.B` is generic

Answer (score 5):

Although the inner class B does not declare any type variables, an instance of it implicitly references an instance of the outer class, which does.

> Why did I get this warning?

```
Test<Integer> t = null;
Test.B b = t.new B(); //warning Test.B is a raw type
```

Because you declared the variable b with a raw type. Instead, you could declare:

```
Test<Integer>.B b = t.new B(); // no warning!
```

Comment: Because it has type parameters that are not specified.

Answer (score 2):

You do not really use the generic type. I will explain it on a slightly more elaborate example:

```
public class Test<T> {  
    public B method(T t) {
        B b = new B(t);
        return (b);
    }

    public class B {
        T value;

        public B(T value) {
            this.value = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here you can see clearly, that `B` depends on the generic parameter `T`, without being generic itself. As [explained by Andy Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31146892/4216641), an instance of `B` can only be created in co-existence with an instance of `Test`. Therefore, `B` is (indirectly) generic. In your given example:

```
Test<Integer> t = null;
Test.B b = t.new B(); //warning Test.B is a raw type
```

`b` does not specify a generic parameter, but `t` does. This is, why you get the warning.

The proper way to write this code would be:

```
Test<Integer> t = null;
Test<Integer>.B b = t.new B();
```

With this, `B` is fully specified and the types match.

Answer (score 2):

Although B is not parameterized, `Test.B b = t.new B();` contains a raw reference to Test, which is parameterized. I got the warning to disappear when I changed the warning line to `Test<Integer>.B b = t.new B();`

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying is not working because B's type is not B but `Test<T>.B`

To get this to work, make class B static.

```
public static class B{ }
```

Answer (score 1):

`B` is an inner class. It cannot exist without an instance of `Test`. Thus, it also depends on any type parameters of `Test`. When compiled, class `B` is transformed into the following:

```
public class Test$B {
  public Test$B(Test paramTest) {}
}
```

(That's what you'll get if you compile it and then decompile it.)

You can see that it takes an `Test` in its constructor. Though type parameters are erased when compiling, if you wrote a class like that yourself, you would probably give it a type parameter to be passed along to `Test`.